# Can't import sklearn

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn, svm, python-import

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3vwH.jpg)

I have both numpy and scipy installed. I also have installed sklearn but can't import it. look at the Image, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem. first uninstalled the scikit-learn using `conda remove scikit-learn`
and then installed it with this command: `conda install scikit-learn`.

Comment: Be careful. This could break a lot of things in Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading the packages to their latest version?

```
pip install -U numpy scikit-learn scipy
```

Or you may try to reinstall some of the packages with the --no-binary option:

```
pip install --force --no-binary scikit-learn scikit-learn
```

Comment: Try please the --no-binary reinstall option as given above.

Comment: I copied the code above. After downloading about 9MB some codes appeared on screen and at the end I got this: Rolling back uninstall of scikit-learn

Comment: still the same problem